# Treatment of NaN's

Tags: python, numpy, nan

I have trouble understanding how pandas and/or numpy are handling NaN values. I am extracting subsets of a pandas dataframe in order to compute t-stats, e.g. I want to know whether there is a significant difference in the mean of x2 for the group whose x1 value is A compared to those with an x1 value of B (apologies for not making this a working example, but I don't know how to recreate the NaN values that pop up in my dataframe, the original data is read in using read_csv, with the csv denoting missing values with `NA`):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import scipy.stats as st
A = data[data['x1']=='A']['x2']
B = data[data['x1']=='B'].x2
A

2      3
3      1
5      2
6      3
10     3
12     2
15     2
16     0
21     0
24     1
25     1
28   NaN
31     0
32     3
...
677     0
681   NaN
682     3
683     1
686     2
Name: praxiserf, Length: 335, dtype: float64
```

That is, I have two `pandas.core.series.Series` objects, which I then want to perform a t-test on. However, using

```
st.ttest_ind(A, B)
```

returns:

```
(array(nan), nan)
```

I presume this has to do with the fact that `ttest_ind` accepts arrays as inputs and there seems to be a problem with my NaN values when converting the series to an array. If I try to calculate means of the original series, I get:

```
A.mean(), B.mean()

1.5802, 1.2
```

However, when I try to turn the series into an array, I get:

```
A_array = np.asarray(A)
A_array

array([ 3., 1., 2., 3., 3., 2., 2., 0., 0., 1., 1.,
        nan, 0., 3., ..., 1., nan, 0., 3. ])
```

That is, `NaN` turned into `nan` and taking means doesn't work anymore:

```
A.mean()

nan
```

How should the missing values be treated in order to ensure that I can still do calculations with the series/array?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`pandas` uses the same code as the `bottleneck` `nanmean` function, I believe, thus automatically ignoring `nan`s. `numpy` doesn't do that for you. What you really want to do, however, is mask the `nan`-values in both series and pass that to the t-test:

```python
mask = numpy.logical_and(numpy.isfinite(A), numpy.isfinite(B))
st.ttest_ind(A[mask], B[mask])
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked perfectly, with the slight caveat that `numpy.logical_and` only seems to work if `A` and `B` have the same size, so I simply used one line `st.ttest_ind(A[np.isfinite(A)], B[np.isfinite(B)])`

Answer (score 1):

ttest_ind takes a parameter called "nan_policy" that dictates how nans are treated.  By default nan_policy is "propagate" which results in nan if any values in the input are nan.  "raise" will raise an error if any inputs are nan.  "omit" ignores nan.

```
st.ttest_ind(A, B, nan_policy="omit")
```

should give you a non-nan result.